# .NET Core 3.1 ChangePasswordAsync Inner Exception "Cannot update Identity column"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity, .net-core-3.1

I am upgrading a .NET Core Web API from 2.2 to 3.1. When testing the `ChangePasswordAsync` function, I receive the following error message:

> Cannot update identity column 'UserId'.

I ran a SQL Profile and I can see that the Identity column is not included in the 2.2 UPDATE statement but it is in 3.1.

The line of code in question returns NULL, as opposed to success or errors, and is as follows:

```
objResult = await this.UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(objUser, objChangePassword.OldPassword, objChangePassword.NewPassword);
```

The implementation of the `ChangePasswordAsnyc` is as follows (code truncated for brevity).

Note: AspNetUsers extends IdentityUser.

```
[HttpPost("/[controller]/change-password")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePasswordAsync([FromBody] ChangePassword objChangePassword)
{
    AspNetUsers objUser = null; 
    IdentityResult objResult = null;    

    // retrieve strUserId from the token.

    objUser = await this.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(strUserId);
    objResult = await this.UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(objUser, objChangePassword.OldPassword, objChangePassword.NewPassword);
    if (!objResult.Succeeded)
    {
        // Handle error.
    }

    return this.Ok(new User(objUser));
}
```

The `UserId` is included in the objResult, along with a lot of other fields, which is then returned at the end of the method. From what I can tell, without being able to step through the `ChangePasswordAsync` method, the function updates all fields that are contained in the `objUser`.

**Question:**

How do I suppress the identity column from being populated in the UPDATE statement that `ChangePasswordAsnyc` is generating?  Do I need to add an attribute in the model? Do I need to remove the `UserId` from the `objUser` before passing it into the `ChangePasswordAsync`? Or, something else?

**Bounty Question**
I have created a custom user class that extends the `IdentityUser` class. In this custom class, there is an additional IDENTITY column. In upgrading the .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1, the `ChangePasswordAsync` function no longer works because the 3.1 method is trying to UPDATE this IDENTITY column whereas this does not happen in 2.1.

There was no code change other than upgrading an installing the relevant packages. The accepted answer needs to fix the problem.

**UPDATE**

Migrations are not used as this results in a forced marriage between the database and the Web API with it's associated models. In my opinion, this violated the separation of duties between database, API, and UI. But, that's Microsoft up to its old ways again.

I have my own defined ADD, UPDATE, and DELETE methods that use EF and set the EntityState. But, when stepping through the code for `ChangePasswordAsync`, I do not see any of these functions called. It is as if `ChangePasswordAsync` uses the base methods in EF. So, I do not know how to modify this behavior.  from Ivan's answer.

Note: I did post a question to try and understand how the `ChangePasswordAsync` method calls EF here [Can someone please explain how the ChangePasswordAsnyc method works?][1].

**namespace ABC.Model.AspNetCore**

```
using ABC.Common.Interfaces;
using ABC.Model.Clients;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ABC.Model.AspNetCore
{
    // Class for AspNetUsers model
    public class AspNetUsers : IdentityUser
    {
        public AspNetUsers()
        {
            // Construct the AspNetUsers object to have some default values here.
        }

        public AspNetUsers(User objUser) : this()
        {
            // Populate the values of the AspNetUsers object with the values found in the objUser passed if it is not null.
            if (objUser != null)
            {
                this.UserId = objUser.UserId; // This is the problem field.
                this.Email = objUser.Email;
                this.Id = objUser.AspNetUsersId;
                // Other fields.
            }
        }

        // All of the properties added to the IdentityUser base class that are extra fields in the AspNetUsers table.
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; } 
        // Other fields.
    }
}
```

**namespace ABC.Model.Clients**

```
using ABC.Model.AspNetCore;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Models;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ABC.Model.Clients
{
    public class User : Identifiable
    {
        public User()
        {
            // Construct the User object to have some default values show when creating a new object.
        }

        public User(AspNetUsers objUser) : this()
        {
            // Populate the values of the User object with the values found in the objUser passed if it is not null.
            if (objUser != null)
            {
                this.AspNetUsersId = objUser.Id;
                this.Id = objUser.UserId;    // Since the Identifiable is of type Identifiable<int> we use the UserIdas the Id value.
                this.Email = objUser.Email;
                // Other fields.
            }
        }

        // Properties
        [Attr("asp-net-users-id")]
        public string AspNetUsersId { get; set; }

        [Attr("user-id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Attr("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Attr("user-name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        // Other fields.
    }
}
```

EntitiesRepo

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ABC.Data.Infrastructure
{  
    public abstract class EntitiesRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
    {
        #region Member Variables
        protected Entities m_DbContext = null;
        protected DbSet<T> m_DbSet = null;
        #endregion


        public virtual void Update(T objEntity)
        {
            this.m_DbSet.Attach(objEntity);
            this.DbContext.Entry(objEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: did you upgrade your entityframework too?

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, I updated all of the packages in NuGet to their most recent version.

Comment: You could extend IdentityUser to include a unique field that contains the old UserId, and have your other tables link to that instead

Comment: @PedroCoelho I'm not sure how adding another field solves the problem of trying to update an already existing field that is an identity column.

Comment: For me, this is yet another proof that you better leave the ASP.Net identity model unaltered. If you want to extend it, create your own tables/classes and link them to the ASP.Net objects. Also, IMO this is a bug. An identity column should never be marked as modified. Not sure if EF core 3 is the culprit or ASP.Net-core Identity.

Comment: @Gert Variable name `strUserId` sounds like `string` data type. Wondering how it could be identity then.

Comment: @IvanStoev it is UserId, not strUserId, of type Int.

Comment: @GertArnold Any chance you can confirm where the bug lies? I will be happy to file a bug on Git. I am strongly leaning towards EF.

Comment: @JWeezy So you are using identity column which is not the PK? Please confirm that, or better add the relevant part of your custom user class and fluent configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure exactly when this happened, but the same behavior exists in the latest EF Core 2 (2.2.6), and also is exactly the same issue as in the following SO question [Auto increment non key value entity framework core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665180/auto-increment-non-key-value-entity-framework-core-2-0/48667529#48667529). Hence there is not much that I can add to my answer there:

> The problem here is that for identity columns (i.e. `ValueGeneratedOnAdd`) which are **not part of a key**, the `AfterSaveBehavior` is `Save`, which in turn makes `Update` method to mark them as modified, which in turn generates wrong `UPDATE` command.
>
> To fix that, you have to set the `AfterSaveBehavior` like this (inside `OnModelCreating` override):
>
> ...

The only difference in 3.x is that now instead of `AfterSaveBehavior` property you have `GetAfterSaveBehavior` and `SetAfterSaveBehavior` methods. To let EF Core always exclude the property from updates, use `SetAfterSaveBehavior` with `PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore`, e.g.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

...

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUsers>(builder =>
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.UserId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore); // <--
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your research on isolating the fact that this is an EF bug. With respect to the solution, please see my update.

Comment: Other than the actual entity and property name, what exactly is added in your update? The above solution should have fixed the issue in question, isn't it? At some point `UserManager` asks `IUserStore` to "update the user", ane EF Core implementation of `IUserStore` is calling `Update` method of the dbset  or dbcontext.  Then EF Core `SaveChanges()` generates wrong `UPDATE` command. Configuring EF Core update behavior as suggested should generically fix the issue. Note that it has nothing to do with migrations, because the setting controls only EF Core runtime behavior.

Comment: I have posted an update. The challenge here is how to exclude the UserId property from the Entity when the incoming collection is generic? In other words, the property is not available in intellisense. Do I need to setup a foreach loop and search for the property in the collection? Or, am I going to have to work at a higher level where the actual IdentityUser sends commands to the `EntityRepositoryBase`. Note: none of this code its executed when stepping into `ChangePasswordAsync`

Comment: Not sure what challenge are you talking about.  The suggested solution is at EF Core entity **configuration** level, so it handles **all** usages - `UserManager`, your generic code etc. Whatever the code does, `UserId` value will not be included in `UPDATE` command. Which was your question. *"The accepted answer needs to fix the problem."*, I believe the above does fix the problem, have you tried it and what's the issue with it?

Comment: If by "challenge here" you mean the *"What is best practice to exclude property from incoming generic collection?"* question in your last "update", I'm afraid it's a brand new question which falls outside the scope of the original post, hence should be asked in a separate post with different tags.

Comment: Thank you! Also, you basically explained how `CreatePasswordAsync` saves through EF, which I have a separate question on. If you want to answer that then I will check it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60444513/can-someone-please-explain-how-the-changepasswordasnyc-method-works

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the 'EntityState' property to mark the proptery as unmodified?

```
db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(model).Property(x => x.UserId).IsModified = false;
db.SaveChanges();
```

see
[Exclude Property on Update in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661881/exclude-property-on-update-in-entity-framework)
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state

Answer (score 0):

Create and Run migrations:

```
dotnet ef migrations add IdentityColumn
dotnet ef database update
```

Comment: Migrations are not used as this results in a forced marriage between the database and the WebApi with it's associated models. In our opinion, this violated the separation of duties between database, API, and UI. But, that's Microsoft up to its old ways again.

Comment: You would then have to manually make sure all the needed columns are available in the DB...

Comment: Correct. However, that is not what is at issue here. There appears to be a bug introduced in EF 3.0. See `Gert Arnold's` comment to my question.