# Is ChangePasswordAsync for ASP .Net Core 3.1 available on GitHub?

Tags: c#, github, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity, .net-core-3.1

This is related to [.NET Core 3.1 ChangePasswordAsync Inner Exception “Cannot update Identity column”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60410556/net-core-3-1-changepasswordasync-inner-exception-cannot-update-identity-column?noredirect=1#comment106891648_60410556)

I am attempting to understand how `ChangePasswordAsync` works and was looking for it on Github. I found an archived version from an older version of Identity that is now locked. But, I prefer to have the current version in order to identify any potential breaking change. Does anyone know where the current development copy of it is?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.changepasswordasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Any help is appreciated it.

Comment: [You mean this?](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L788)

Comment: @rain336  Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the ASP.NET Core project in this [Github project](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore). And the `ChangePasswordAsync` can be found in the `UserManager.cs` file [just here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#LC777).