# Can someone please explain how the ChangePasswordAsnyc method works?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

This is related to [net-core-3-1-changepasswordasync-inner-exception-cannot-update-identity-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60410556/net-core-3-1-changepasswordasync-inner-exception-cannot-update-identity-column).

I have gone through the method's source code in Git, found here [ChangePasswordAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#LC777).

My understanding is that this method uses EntityFramework (EF), but I am not understanding the link between this method and EF. Specifically, how does EF generate the UPDATE SQL command?

From what I can tell, the method just makes calls to other functions within UserManager.cs, without actually making a call to a function that is defined in EF. So, I am a bit mystified, for lack of a better word, as to how the UPDATE SQL command is created.

**Background**

This is part of a .NET Core Web Api migration project from 2.2 to 3.1. The code has not changed and I preserved a copy of the existing 2.2 project in order to run testing. But, for some reason, I am getting an IDENTITY update failure in 3.1, which is no happening in 2.2. The cause is that 3.1 is now including the IDENTITY column in the UPDATE script (I can see this in SQL Profiler) whereas 2.2 omitted it. My best bet is that either a breaking change was made in either the method's migration from 2.2 to 3.1 or there was a change made somewhere in EF's migration from 2.2 to 3.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

`ChangePasswordAsync` from `UserManager.cs`

```
/// <summary>
/// Changes a user's password after confirming the specified <paramref name="currentPassword"/> is correct,
/// as an asynchronous operation.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="user">The user whose password should be set.</param>
/// <param name="currentPassword">The current password to validate before changing.</param>
/// <param name="newPassword">The new password to set for the specified <paramref name="user"/>.</param>
/// <returns>
/// The <see cref="Task"/> that represents the asynchronous operation, containing the <see cref="IdentityResult"/>
/// of the operation.
/// </returns>
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> ChangePasswordAsync(TUser user, string currentPassword, string newPassword)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    var passwordStore = GetPasswordStore();
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
    }


    if (await VerifyPasswordAsync(passwordStore, user, currentPassword) != PasswordVerificationResult.Failed)
    {
        var result = await UpdatePasswordHash(passwordStore, user, newPassword);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return result;
        }
        return await UpdateUserAsync(user);
    }
    Logger.LogWarning(2, "Change password failed for user {userId}.", await GetUserIdAsync(user));
    return IdentityResult.Failed(ErrorDescriber.PasswordMismatch());
}
```

Comment: Iti s quite obvious that what you ask for is NOT in the method you posted. It actually calls other methods. Did you look at their code= Bascially you need to look at the called methods in the specific implementtation of the password store that GePasswordStore returns.

Comment: @TomTom Yeah, but where? I already mentioned that I went through the code and I cannot find the link to EF. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can promise you taht there is a linked model library doing that. What does GetPasswordStore return? where is this used? In our case we wrote our own storage manager. Simply said: it returns a base class or something. If you do not know how to find where tis is used in your codebase or where this is imported from, you should learn visual studio context menues a LOT better.

Comment: What might help is downloading the source from github and then setting up visual studio that when you F12 (go to source) you go directly into their source. it's easier to browse that way than from github